# I will be afraid of neither rain nor of snow. Correct?

Tags: neither-nor

> I will be afraid of neither rain nor of snow
>
> I will be afraid neither of rain nor of snow.
>
> I will be afraid of
>   neither rain nor snow.

What is the correct usage?

Comment: All three are acceptable.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you have any reference why all of them are acceptable? The 3-rd one sounds good but the other 2 - not so much. I don't think `of` before `snow` is needed.

Comment: 'Of' before snow is not needed, and can be omitted, but it is correct if used, and we can use repetition to add emphasis or rhythm. I am afraid neither of men, nor of women, nor of wild beasts, nor of tempests on the ocean. Multiple 'nors' after 'neither' are grammatical, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I think 2 and 3 are fine, but 1 is not, because when you say

> I will be afraid of neither...

two options are expected. You then present us with options

> A) ... rain.
> B)... of snow.

That second *of* is off (pun intended).

Comment: Do you want to rebuke Matthew Arnold? "Ah, love, let us be true
To one another! for the world, which seems
To lie before us like a land of dreams,
So various, so beautiful, so new,
Hath really neither joy, nor love, nor light,
Nor certitude, nor peace, nor help for pain;

Comment: Or Kipling? "But there is neither East nor West, Border, nor Breed, nor Birth,

When two strong men stand face to face, though they come from the ends of the earth!"

Comment: "That second of is off (pun intended)." - nonsense,

Comment: But it was such a good pun... :(

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Your examples seem to be hitting more than two items rather than the "of" in the second one.  Maybe "neither of rain nor of snow."

Answer (score 1):

All three are acceptable.

The third is probably preferred, but 1 and 2 are also correct.

The style is rather formal, and the use of "I will" (rather than I'll) expresses "determination" rather than a simple prediction of the future.  And generally rain and snow are not considered scary, so the meaning is rather odd.